# One page site using Mootools Scroll + jQuery to highlight Nav Anchor Links?

Tags: jquery, scroll, navigation, mootools

Okay, I'm about 2 inches away from solving my problem, and now I'm not sure how to proceed.

Dev site: http://www.kendraschaefer.com/meilin

I'm using Mootools and jQuery in the same page to create a one-page site. Mootools handles the page scrolling - page scrolls up and down within a specified div.

Jquery handles all other effects.

The problem is the navigation bar - I'm trying to get the nav items to highlight based on which div is currently active.

I finally settled on the following solution before realizing it doesn't quite cut it:

- MooTools handles scrolling
- Jquery assigns a "current" class to any nav item that's clicked, and removes the "current" class from any other nav item.

The problem: I now can't create in-page links, because in-page links aren't hooked up to the nav in any way. For example, on the "home" page, try clicking the "work" or "team" buttons in the content area - appropriate nav items aren't selected, and I don't know how to make that work.

Maybe I should add the class assignment via Mootools after the scroll takes effect? (If you know how, please share!)

Or maybe I should modify the Jquery?

Any and all solutions welcome! Thanks!

Comment: i see you've done it in jquery. you really ought to think of doing the menu -> element to scrollTo relationship to be dynamic so you don't add nnn click events individually to all menu links but rather add apply the same callback to a selector like `#menu a`. if you used mootools 1.2+ you could have even assigned event delegation (1.11 is a bit old - nearly 4 hrs now). another thing you should be able to do is use the onStart/ onComplete events on the Fx.base class, eg. your instance can have the event and the click passes it back the trigger element: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/WkTzr/

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution to the house of cards I have there - thanks!. If you have any idea how to incorporate the in-page links into that, I'd quickly make the switch. I'm much more comfortable with jQuery than I am with MooTools, hence the strange syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll = new Fx.Scroll('contentouter', {
    duration: 1000,
    wait: false,
    offset: {
        'x': -200,
        'y': -40
    },
    onStart: function() {
        // do it here str after click and before scroll
        $$("a.current").removeClass("current");
        if (this.triggerEl)
            this.triggerEl.addClass("current");
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        // or have it here after the scroll is done

    },
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut
});

var scrollableLinks = $$("a").filter(function(link) {
    var href = link.getProperty("href");
    return href && href.contains("#") && href.replace("#", '').length;
});

scrollableLinks.each(function(el) {
    el.addEvents({
        click: function(e) {
            new Event(e).stop();
            scroll.triggerEl = this;
            scroll.toElement(this.getProperty("href").replace("#", ''));
        }
    });
});
```

the scrollableLinks works with your current markup to fetch all page links that have a href and it contains # and it's not just #

in later versions like 1.2, 1.3 you could have just applied it to all anchor links like so:

`document.getElements("a[href~=#]")`

another way is to create a simple 'nav' class, and if you want a link to act as the nav ones, simply do `<a href="#about" class="nav">about us</a>` - doing a generic catch-all may make it difficult to have regular anchors.

updated example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/WkTzr/6/ where the TEAM image on first container is a link that replicates the top menu link.

Comment: This code is lovely, and forgive my total ignorance, but still doesn't solve the original problem - if I click the "team" link, for example, the "Our Team" nav item does not highlight - am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: nah you are right. it needs some logic to determine if the the trigger link has a parent #nav and if not, loop through the ones in nav and find the matching one (by href), then using `fireEvent("click")` but seeing as it's friday night i cant devote it more time atm. if its still an issue for you past the weekend i will take another look.

Comment: I completely understand - thanks so much for all you've done.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/WkTzr/7/ - it will add the highlight if there's a matching element in the nav links